# Using GWT and JDO, why does execute query always return null?

Tags: gwt, null, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I have been working with GWT the last couple of months and the very last thing that I need to get to work is storing my applications data in JDO-objects with GAE instead of SQLITE.
My application successfully saves the object (in this case a forum topic) to the datastore (I have confirmed this in the appspot/appengine log viewer). I have managed to fetch one of the objects when I hard-code the topic ID like this:

```
 pManager.getObjectById(Topic.class, 1);
```

But when I try to use the Query class and fetch a List with all my topics all I get from the execute method is null. If I clear the datastore of topics I can print the size of the resulting List (hence it should not be null) but when there is Topics in the datastore it always makes the `List<Topic> null`.

Here is the code in question:

```
// Fetches all Topic-objects from the App Engine storage and 
// puts them in an ArrayList that is returned.
public ArrayList<Topic> getAllTopics() {

    ArrayList<Topic> queryResults = new ArrayList<Topic>();
    PersistenceManager pManager = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    pManager.getFetchPlan().setGroup(FetchGroup.ALL);
    Query topicQuery = pManager.newQuery(Topic.class);

    // Does not make any difference what query I use
    //Query topicQuery = pManager.newQuery(Topic.class);

    Topic newTopic = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("Will now try to execute the query...");
        List<Topic> results = (List<Topic>)topicQuery.execute();
        System.out.println("Result size: " + results.size());
        System.out.println("Query now done executing.");
        for (Topic t : results) {
            // Does not seem to make any difference either
            //      newTopic = pManager.detachCopy(t);
            //      queryResults.add(newTopic);
            queryResults.add(t);
        }
        // I can fetch one topic when hard-coding the ID.
        //      queryResults.add(pManager.getObjectById(Topic.class, 1));
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception when getting all topics on server: " + e.getMessage() + " - ");
        System.out.print( e.getStackTrace());
    } finally {
        topicQuery.closeAll();
        pManager.close();
    }   


    return queryResults;
}
```

And here is the code that makes the Topic objevts persistant:

```
    // Creates a topic object and stores it in App Engine
// Returns true if it succeeded, otherwise false
public Boolean createTopic(String title_, String text_) {

    PersistenceManager pManager = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    UserAuthImpl newUserAuth = new UserAuthImpl();

    if(newUserAuth.returnUser().isEmpty() || newUserAuth.returnUser() == null ) 
        return false;

    Topic newTopic = new Topic(newUserAuth.returnUser(), title_, text_, new Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));

    try {
        // Did not help: pManager.setDetachAllOnCommit(true);
        pManager.makePersistent(newTopic);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error while creating topic: " + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    } finally {
        pManager.close();
    }
    return true;
}
```

And here is the Topic object class:

```
package se.biffnet.tddi15.forum.client;

import java.io.Serializable;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.jdo.annotations.IdGeneratorStrategy;
import javax.jdo.annotations.IdentityType;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable = "true")
public class Topic implements Serializable {

@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
long    topicID;

@Persistent
String  authorID;

@Persistent
String  postTitle;

@Persistent
String  postText;

@Persistent
Date    postDate;

public Topic(String authorID_, String postTitle_, String postText_, 
        java.util.Date date) {
    authorID    = authorID_;
    postTitle   = postTitle_;
    postText    = postText_;
}

public Topic() {
    authorID    = "";
    postTitle   = "";
    postText    = "";
    postDate    = null;
}

public String getPostTitle() {
    return postTitle;
}

public void setPostTitle(String postTitle) {
    this.postTitle = postTitle;
}

public String getPostText() {
    return postText;
}

public void setPostText(String postText) {
    this.postText = postText;
}

public long getTopicID() {
    return topicID;
}

public String getAuthorID() {
    return authorID;
}

public Date getPostDate() {
    return postDate;
    } 
}
```

So I guess the question is: 
Why does `execute()` always return null? Help much appreciated =)

EDIT2: Had to change the logging.properties to be able to see the debug messages. It was my bad. The log is to large to post here, so here is a link to pastebin: http://pastebin.com/CGX1Aug0

EDIT3: The exception and its stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.QueryEntityPKFetchFieldManager.fetchLongField(QueryEntityPKFetchFieldManager.java:74)
org.datanucleus.identity.IdentityUtils.getApplicationIdentityForResultSetRow(IdentityUtils.java:101)
com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils.entityToPojo(EntityUtils.java:1011)
com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.DatastoreQuery$2.apply(DatastoreQuery.java:229)
com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.DatastoreQuery$2.apply(DatastoreQuery.java:226)
com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.LazyResult.resolveNext(LazyResult.java:96)
com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.LazyResult$LazyAbstractListIterator.computeNext(LazyResult.java:229)
com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:131)
com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:126)
com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.LazyResult$AbstractListIterator.hasNext(LazyResult.java:183)
se.biffnet.tddi15.forum.server.DbHandlerImpl.getAllTopics(DbHandlerImpl.java:75)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_$1.run(Method_.java:167)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_.privilegedInvoke(Method_.java:164)
com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_.invoke_(Method_.java:125)
com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_.invoke(Method_.java:43)
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:57)
org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:438)
com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:480)
com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:487)
com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:774)
com.google.tracing.TraceContext$DoInTraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:751)
com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:342)
com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:334)
com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:484)
com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: I'm sure you have a log there ... and you could configure it to DEBUG level.

Comment: nope. Thats the log to INFO level. At DEBUG level you would get pages of info. And if there is an exception then best to provide it and stack trace

Comment: That was my bad, did not know I had to edit the logging.properties file. I have editet the post with a link to pastebin with the log since it was to large for the post.

Comment: So address the "I 2013-04-07 11:12:16.029
[s~hubbele/1.366501598003882339].<stdout>: Exception when getting all topics on server: null -" and what is the exception (you don't say) and the stack trace (neither). It obviously returns non-null on ALL GAE plugin testcases which are all public http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Ftests%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fappengine%2Fdatanucleus

Comment: Added stacktrace. The exception seems to occur when I try to use the result list.